# Where can I find the InlinePageParser class?

Tags: parsing, razor, dynamic-compilation

Having found several examples for parsing cshmtl files, I would like to experiment a bit myself, yet I can't find the class `InlinePageParser` in any assembly or namespace available to me. I have MVC3 and 4 installed with VS 2012, and I have WebMatrix.

The example I'm looking at has imports:

```
using Microsoft.WebPages.Compilation;
using Microsoft.WebPages.Compilation.Parser;
```

Some readin reveals that `Microsoft.WebPages` has been replaced by `System.Razor`, but the new namespace only has `System.Web.Razor.Parser` which knows nothing about `InlinePageParser`. How can a class just vanish like that? Did it do something terrible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class is now called [`RazorParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.razor.parser.razorparser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and is part of the `System.Web.Razor.dll` assembly.